# AutoCompleteTextView arrayList update not working when fragment changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

Frist, I have weak English skill.

I use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager and fragment.

When I swipe the fragment page, want to update for AutoCompleteTextView adapter.

try
1.combination for (clear, set, notify..)  in `onPageSelected(int position)`

```
aList.clear();  
autoSearchAdapter.clear();  
autoTextView.setAdapter(autoSearchAdapter);  
autoSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

2. use handler in `onPageSelected(int position)`

hint. sometimes AutoCompleteTextView arrayList working.(50%) and It is working after writing sentence in AutoCompleteTextView , swipe the page. at this moment arraylist expanded. also all list visible.

part of code
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
static String uName;
TestAdapter demoPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

static AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView;
static ArrayAdapter<String> autoSearchAdapter;
public static ArrayList<String> aList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //hide actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // fragments, so use getSupportFragmentManager.
    demoPagerAdapter = new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(demoPagerAdapter);

    getAccountInfo();

    SetAutoSearchAdapter();

    KeyBoardHide();

}
private void SetAutoSearchAdapter(){
    //AutoCompleteTextView setting
    autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_textview);
    aList=new ArrayList<String>();
    autoSearchAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, aList);
    autosearchInit();
    autoTextView.setAdapter(autoSearchAdapter);

    //updating autosearch adapter
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                aList.clear();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fragment 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //autosearchInit();
                aList.add("aaaaaa00");
                aList.add("bbbbb00");
                aList.add("ccccc00");
                autoSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fragment 1.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                aList.clear();
                aList.add("aaaaaa11");
                aList.add("bbbbb11");
                aList.add("ccccc11");
                autoSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (position == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fragment 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                aList.clear();
                autoSearchAdapter.clear();
                autoTextView.setAdapter(autoSearchAdapter);
                aList.add("aaaaa22");
                aList.add("bbbbb22");
                aList.add("ccccc22");
                autoSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you are doing that wrong way: no need for `setOnPageChangeListener` at all, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: no use setOnPageChangeListener, how do i check the change of fragment?

Comment: you just need to check what is the current page in `runQuery` method, thats all

Comment: ok thank you.  I dont know exactly.   try to your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in autoSearchAdapter you have to create method to set arry list,

```
private ArrayList<Test> test;

Public void setAryList(ArrayList<Test> test){
this.test = test;
}
```

after you have to called

```
autoSearchAdapter.setAryList(aList);  
autoSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it works like charm.

Comment: you mean  use custom adapter instead of [autoSearchAdapter =
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, aList);] ?